# Does IEnumerable always imply a collection?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

Just a quick question regarding `IEnumerable`:

Does `IEnumerable` always imply a collection?  Or is it legitimate/viable/okay/whatever to use on a single object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always and mandatory that `IEnumerable` is used on a **single** object - the single object is always the holder or producer of zero or more **other** objects that do not necessarily have any relation to `IEnumerable`.

It's usual, but not mandatory, that `IEnumerable` represents a collection.

Enumerables can be collections, as well as generators, queries, and even computations.

#### Generator:

```
IEnumerable<int> Generate(
    int initial,
    Func<int, bool> condition,
    Func<int, int> iterator)
{
    var i = initial;
    while (true)
    {
        yield return i;
        i = iterator(i);
        if (!condition(i))
        {
            yield break;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Query:

```
IEnumerable<Process> GetProcessesWhereNameContains(string text)
{
    // Could be web-service or database call too
    var processes = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses();
    foreach (var process in processes)
    {
        if (process.ProcessName.Contains(text))
        {
            yield return process;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Computation:

```
IEnumerable<double> Average(IEnumerable<double> values)
{
    var sum = 0.0;
    var count = 0;
    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        sum += value;
        yield return sum/++count;
    }
}
```

LINQ is itself a series of operators that produce objects that implement `IEnumerable<T>` that don't have any underlying collections.

Good question, BTW!

NB: Any reference to `IEnumerable` also applies to `IEnumerable<T>` as the latter inherits the former.

Answer (score 5):

The `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>` interfaces suggest a sequence of some kind, but that sequence doesn't need to be a concrete collection.

For example, where's the underlying concrete collection in this case?

```
foreach (int i in new EndlessRandomSequence().Take(5))
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}

// ...

public class EndlessRandomSequence : IEnumerable<int>
{
    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        var rng = new Random();
        while (true) yield return rng.Next();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `IEnumerable` implies a collection, or possible collection, of items.

The name is derived from enumerate, which means to:

1. Mention (a number of things) one by one.
2. Establish the number of.

Answer (score 1):

[According to the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx), it exposes the enumerator over a collection.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly use it on a single object, but this object will then just be exposed as an *enumeration* containing a single object, i.e. you could have an `IEnumerable<int>` with a single integer:

```
IEnumerable<int> items = new[] { 42 };
```

Answer (score 1):

`IEnumerable` represents a collection that can be enumerated, not a single item. Look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx); the interface exposes `GetEnumerator()`, which

> ...[r]eturns an enumerator that iterates through a collection.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, IEnumerable always implies a collection, that is what enumerate means.

What is your use case for a single object?

I don't see a problem with using it on a single object, but why do want to do this?

Comment: Just some confusion stemming from reading some tuts about using the Repository pattern with EF4.  And a lack of sleep. :)

Comment: @kevinmajor1 - It may be useful to mention that in your post (the first part at least...)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether you mean a "collection" or a .NET "ICollection" but since other people have only mentioned the former I will mention the latter.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx

By that definition, All ICollections are IEnumerable. But not the other way around.
But most data structure (Array even) just implement both interfaces.

Going on this train of thought: you could have a car depot (a single object) that does not expose an internal data structure, and put IEnumerable on it. I suppose.